# How do I find the center of an image, and place another image on top of it?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

**HTML:**

```
<img src="img/image1.jpg" id = "image1" style="width: 100%;" allign = "center">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var image1 = document.getElementById("image1");
```

How would I get the center of this given image, and then place another image which has an absolute position on top of it dead center?

Comment: Do you mean an image that has a position of center or an image that has the same center?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect()` on the images to find their exact position and calculate using those values. This method will take into consideration the CSS size as well as scroll position etc.

The second image is placed below using fixed position, for demo, but you can use a parent div set to relative and place the image inside that using absolute etc.

#### Example

```js
function centerImages() {
  var image1 = document.getElementById("image1");
  var rect1 = image1.getBoundingClientRect();
  var cx = rect1.left + rect1.width * 0.5;    // find center of first image
  var cy = rect1.top + rect1.height * 0.5;

  var image2 = document.getElementById("image2");
  var rect2 = image2.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = cx - rect2.width * 0.5;            // use center of first, subtract second
  var y = cy - rect2.height * 0.5;
  image2.style.cssText = "position:fixed;left:" + x + "px; top:" + y + "px";
}
window.onload = window.onresize = window.onscroll = centerImages;
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDTPI.gif" id="image1" style="width: 100%;">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk5Js.gif" id="image2">
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/33ra14az/1/ here's a way I came up with using JS + resize event for responsive.

```
function setImg() {
var img1 = document.getElementById('image1'),
    img2 = document.getElementById('image2'),
    offtop = ((img1.offsetHeight/2)-(img2.offsetHeight/2)),
    offleft = ((img1.offsetWidth/2)-(img2.offsetWidth/2));
    img2.style.top = offtop + "px";
    img2.style.left = offleft + "px";
}
window.load = setImg();
window.addEventListener('resize',setImg);
```

Comment: This will add a new listener every time the client window is resized. That is probably not intended..

Answer (score 1):

well you can try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var top=($("#image1").height()/2)-($("#image2").height()/2);
    var left=($("#image1").width()/2)-($("#image2").width()/2);
    $("#image2").css('left',left+'px');
    $("#image2").css('top',top+'px');
});
```

and the css is simple:

```
#image2{
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

and this is the html code:

```
<img src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-logo.png" id = "image1" style="width: 100%;" allign = "center">
    <img src="http://www.hakandemirel.com.tr/blog/wp-content/uploads/jsfiddle.png" id ="image2">
```

this is demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/yysdged6/22/

Comment: @Moneer Kamal It works perfectly in the jsfiddle link however when I tried this on my local, this doesn't work. (The images are not centered) I copied your entire code, js, hmtl and css. Any ideas? I am using Chrome to view the html.

Comment: Have you used inspect element tools to debug this problem ??i think it could be affected by other elements, specially the first parent that takes position relative. can you add a image of what you got??